# C++ STD functional operators: is there a method to map one vector onto another vector through a function?

Tags: c++, std, c++20

Suppose I have two vectors, and I would like to create vector 2, `vector<double>` from vector 1, `vector<string>` through a standard process:

```
// pseudo code
std::map_onto(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),[](string x) -> double {return stod(x);});
```

Is there a way to do this in C++?

Comment: Did you try looking through [algorithm library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)? Why [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) doesn't accomplish what you need?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius that's the one. Totally forgot about it, but knew it existed. Thank you. Closing.

Comment: If there is an implicit conversion sequence you can use `std::copy`.  Otherwise use `std::transform`

Answer (score 0):

You can always simply write some code:

```
for (auto x : v1) {
    v2.push_back(std::stod(x));
}
```

or if `v2` already exists and you wish to overwrite it:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    v2[i] = std::stod(v1[i]);
}
```

or you can use [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::transform(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), std::begin(v2), 
    [](const std::string& s) -> double { return std::stod(s); });
```

Comment: already wrote it, but it was not attractive

Comment: there is a try catch in there that eliminates the cleanliness.  I don't mind collapsing a lambda to a one-liner though, and the transform wraps everything up nicely.

Comment: @donlan Edited answer.